# How to save facebook image into my web server folder using node.js and express

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, express

I need to save the images from the user's album in facebook to my server folder.My server is running in node.js and express.I tried http.get but it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you shall get photo's source using facebook graph api.

Then you'll be able to download this photo using any lib you want.

I recommend you to use [request](https://github.com/voxpelli/node-request) lib, because it can handle SSL and redirects.

Alternative solution is to replace `https://` with `http://`. After that you'll be able to use `http.get`.